# Is $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{B}]$ well-defined when $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{A}]$ is, where $\mathscr{A}\subset\mathscr{B}$ and $X^\pm$ isn't integrable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ be a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbb{P})$,
and let $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$ be sub-$\sigma$-fields of $\mathscr{F}$ such that
$\mathscr{A}\subset\mathscr{B}$.

**Question:**
Is $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{B}]$ well-defined when $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{A}]$ is,
but when both the negative part $X^-$
and the positive part $X^+$ of $X$ are not integrable?

For what I understand by well-defined,
let's consider the definition of conditional expectation
as given by e.g. Shiryaev (*Probability*, 2013; p. 213):

The conditional expectation of $X^\pm$
with respect to $\mathscr{A}$
is an $\mathscr{A}$-measurable random variable
$\mathbb{E}[X^\pm|\mathscr{A}]$ satisfying for every $A\in\mathscr{A}$ that
\begin{equation*}
\int_A\mathbb{E}[X^\pm|\mathscr{A}]d\mathbb{P} = \int_A X^\pm d\mathbb{P}.
\end{equation*}
If $\mathbb{E}[X^-|\mathscr{A}]\wedge\mathbb{E}[X^+|\mathscr{A}] < \infty$ almost surely
then the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{A}]$
of $X$ with respect to $\mathscr{A}$
is said to be well-defined and is given by
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{A}] = \mathbb{E}[X^+|\mathscr{A}] - \mathbb{E}[X^-|\mathscr{A}].
\end{equation*}

In other words,
does
$\mathbb{E}[X^-|\mathscr{A}]\wedge\mathbb{E}[X^+|\mathscr{A}] < \infty$ almost surely
imply
$\mathbb{E}[X^-|\mathscr{B}]\wedge\mathbb{E}[X^+|\mathscr{B}] < \infty$ almost surely?

My attempt so far:

Let $B$ be the event in $\mathscr{B}$ on which
$\mathbb{E}[X^-|\mathscr{B}] = \mathbb{E}[X^+|\mathscr{B}] = \infty$.
For every $A\in\mathscr{A}$ satisfying $B\subseteq A$
it holds that
\begin{equation*}
\infty\mathbb{P}(B)
=\int_B\mathbb{E}[X^\pm|\mathscr{B}]d\mathbb{P}
=\int_B X^\pm d\mathbb{P}
\leq
\int_A X^\pm d\mathbb{P}
=\int_A\mathbb{E}[X^\pm|\mathscr{A}]d\mathbb{P}.
\end{equation*}
Suppose that $\mathscr{A}$ is generated by a finite or countable partition.
Then there is a smallest $A\in\mathscr{A}$ satisfying $B\subseteq A$.
Either $\mathbb{P}(A) = 0$,
or on $A$ we have that $\mathbb{E}[X^\pm|\mathscr{A}]$
equals $\frac{1}{\mathbb{P}(A)}\int_A X^\pm d\mathbb{P}$.
Since by assumption $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{A}]$ is well-defined,
either $\mathbb{P}(A) = 0$ or
at least one of $\int_A X^-d\mathbb{P}$ and $\int_A X^+d\mathbb{P}$ is finite.
Both possibilities imply that $B$ must have probability zero,
which means that $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{B}]$ is well-defined.

Is there always a set $A\in\mathscr{A}$ satisfying $B\subseteq A$
and small enough such that
at least one of $\int_A X^-d\mathbb{P}$ and $\int_A X^+d\mathbb{P}$ is finite?
This would solve the problem. Or is there some other approach?

(In the first version of this question
I only demanded $X$ to be non-integrable,
but this would still allow for one of
$\int_\Omega X^-d\mathbb{P}$ and $\int_\Omega X^+d\mathbb{P}$
to be finite,
which by the above argument would then imply the well-definedness
of $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{B}]$.
So I restricted to both $X^-$ and $X^+$ being non-integrable.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found a proof that the event $B$ in $\mathscr{B}$ on which
$\mathbb{E}[X^-|\mathscr{B}] = \mathbb{E}[X^+|\mathscr{B}] = \infty$
has probability zero,
thereby showing that $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{B}]$ is well-defined.

Let $A^\pm_\infty = \{\mathbb{E}[X^\pm|\mathscr{A}] = \infty\}$
and for each nonnegative integer $n$
let $A^\pm_n = \{n\leq\mathbb{E}[X^\pm|\mathscr{A}]\leq n+1\}$.
These events lie in $\mathscr{A}$ and satisfy
$\Omega = \big(\bigcup^\infty_{n=0}A^\pm_n\big)\cup A^\pm_\infty$,
hence
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{P}(B)
&=
\sum^\infty_{n=0}
\mathbb{P}(B\cap A^-_n)
+
\mathbb{P}(B\cap A^-_\infty)
\\
&=
\sum^\infty_{n=0}
\mathbb{P}(B\cap A^-_n)
+
\sum^\infty_{n=0}
\mathbb{P}(B\cap A^-_\infty\cap A^+_n)
+
\mathbb{P}(B\cap A^-_\infty\cap A^+_\infty)
.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
By assumption $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{A}]$ is well-defined,
which means that $\mathbb{P}(A^-_\infty\cap A^+_\infty) = 0$,
and for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ we have
\begin{multline*}
\infty\mathbb{P}(B\cap A^-_n)
=
\int_{B\cap A^-_n}
\mathbb{E}[X^-|\mathscr{B}]
d\mathbb{P}
=
\int_{B\cap A^-_n}
X^-
d\mathbb{P}
\\
\leq
\int_{A^-_n}
X^-
d\mathbb{P}
=
\int_{A^-_n}
\mathbb{E}[X^-|\mathscr{A}]
d\mathbb{P}
\leq
(n+1)\mathbb{P}(A^-_n)
<
\infty
\end{multline*}
and
\begin{multline*}
\infty\mathbb{P}(B\cap A^-_\infty\cap A^+_n)
=
\int_{B\cap A^-_\infty\cap A^+_n}
\mathbb{E}[X^+|\mathscr{B}]
d\mathbb{P}
=
\int_{B\cap A^-_\infty\cap A^+_n}
X^+
d\mathbb{P}
\\
\leq
\int_{A^+_n}
X^+
d\mathbb{P}
=
\int_{A^+_n}
\mathbb{E}[X^+|\mathscr{A}]
d\mathbb{P}
\leq
(n+1)\mathbb{P}(A^+_n)
<
\infty
,
\end{multline*}
which means that
$\mathbb{P}(B\cap A^-_n) = \mathbb{P}(B\cap A^-_\infty\cap A^+_n) = 0$
for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
From this we can conclude that $B$ has probability zero,
and thus $\mathbb{E}[X|\mathscr{B}]$ is well-defined.